# Add followers' list at the end of discussion

Tags: users, nodes

I want to add following functionalities in Drupal 7.

- Any forum-user can have followers, So I want to show followers list on forum-user's profile page. (Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfXzU.jpg))
- Those followers should be automatically subscribed to all the posts by that author.

I'm using [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module. How to do this using Views module or any other possible way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@NishantP's link helped me to understand a bit, but [this](http://ymbra.com/blog/allow-users-follow-each-other-views-and-flag-drupal) post solved the issue perfectly. Its Author has elaborated nicely.

Modules used : Views, Flag, CTools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module.

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by
>   the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can
>   provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other
>   type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking
>   important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views
>   integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep
>   tabs on important content.

[Creating Following & Followers](http://www.leesome.com/blog/2013/02/18/creating-following-and-followers-tabs-with-flags-in-drupal-7/)